# How do we create siblings composition column out of gender and family id and individual id columns in R

Tags: r

I applied the suggested code to the original dataset. But it didn't produced the desired result in the siblings_composition column such that 1 for at least 1 male sibling, 2 for at least 1 female sibling, 3 for both male and female siblings and 0 for no siblings. In the original dataset BIRIMNO is for family_id, CINSIYET is for gender and id is for individual_id. As an illustration I provide the result which is produced by the code below:

> head(data)

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   BIRIMNO [5]
  BIRIMNO CINSIYET       id siblings_composition
    <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>                <int>
1  144003 F        14400307                    3
2  144003 M        14400306                    3
3  144009 F        14400903                    3
4  144014 M        14401409                    3
5  144015 M        14401501                    2
6  144016 M        14401603                    3
```

For reproducability on the original dataset, the result of:

> dput(head(data, 100))

```
structure(list(BIRIMNO = c(144003, 144003, 144009, 144014, 144015, 
144016, 144020, 144020, 144021, 144025, 144025, 144025, 144028, 
144028, 144029, 144031, 144034, 144036, 144039, 144040, 144042, 
144042, 144046, 144047, 144047, 144049, 144054, 144056, 144056, 
144060, 144061, 144069, 144071, 144071, 144071, 144071, 144073, 
144074, 144074, 144077, 144079, 144080, 144084, 144084, 144084, 
144088, 144088, 144090, 144092, 144092, 144092, 144094, 144113, 
144118, 144120, 144122, 144123, 144123, 144123, 144124, 144127, 
144127, 144129, 144129, 144130, 144134, 144137, 144138, 144151, 
144152, 144154, 144158, 144162, 144162, 144162, 144162, 144163, 
144163, 144163, 144167, 144172, 144172, 144176, 144176, 144181, 
144181, 144183, 144185, 144189, 144202, 144202, 144214, 144215, 
144217, 144219, 144224, 144224, 144247, 144247, 144249), CINSIYET = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("M", "F"), class = "factor"), id = c(14400307, 
14400306, 14400903, 14401409, 14401501, 14401603, 14402003, 14402004, 
14402103, 14402503, 14402505, 14402506, 14402803, 14402804, 14402904, 
14403104, 14403404, 14403603, 14403903, 14404003, 14404205, 14404204, 
14404603, 14404703, 14404704, 14404905, 14405403, 14405603, 14405604, 
14406004, 14406103, 14406903, 14407109, 14407112, 14407111, 14407110, 
14407303, 14407403, 14407404, 14407706, 14407908, 14408006, 14408405, 
14408404, 14408403, 14408803, 14408804, 14409004, 14409204, 14409205, 
14409203, 14409405, 14411303, 14411804, 14412003, 14412203, 14412304, 
14412306, 14412305, 14412407, 14412704, 14412705, 14412906, 14412905, 
14413003, 14413403, 14413703, 14413804, 14415103, 14415203, 14415404, 
14415803, 14416207, 14416204, 14416206, 14416205, 14416306, 14416307, 
14416308, 14416704, 14417204, 14417205, 14417603, 14417604, 14418104, 
14418103, 14418303, 14418503, 14418903, 14420204, 14420203, 14421403, 
14421503, 14421704, 14421903, 14422403, 14422404, 14424704, 14424703, 
14424903), siblings_composition = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    BIRIMNO = c(144003, 144009, 144014, 144015, 144016, 144020, 
    144021, 144025, 144028, 144029, 144031, 144034, 144036, 144039, 
    144040, 144042, 144046, 144047, 144049, 144054, 144056, 144060, 
    144061, 144069, 144071, 144073, 144074, 144077, 144079, 144080, 
    144084, 144088, 144090, 144092, 144094, 144113, 144118, 144120, 
    144122, 144123, 144124, 144127, 144129, 144130, 144134, 144137, 
    144138, 144151, 144152, 144154, 144158, 144162, 144163, 144167, 
    144172, 144176, 144181, 144183, 144185, 144189, 144202, 144214, 
    144215, 144217, 144219, 144224, 144247, 144249), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7:8, 9L, 10:12, 13:14, 15L, 16L, 
        17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21:22, 23L, 24:25, 26L, 27L, 28:29, 
        30L, 31L, 32L, 33:36, 37L, 38:39, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43:45, 
        46:47, 48L, 49:51, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57:59, 60L, 
        61:62, 63:64, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
        73:76, 77:79, 80L, 81:82, 83:84, 85:86, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
        90:91, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96:97, 98:99, 100L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -68L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Many thanks

Comment: your conditiions are not exclusive.. if a subject has a male and female sibling, the new column value should be 1 (at least one male) and/or 3 (male and female sibling) ?

Comment: I believe the problem may lie in the fact that the argument for your function takes "data", but your data.frame is also called "data" (same). You have `data$individual_id != data$individual_id` which is always FALSE. Try calling the function argument something else, like `row_data`, and then set current id and gender to `row_data$family_id` and `row_data$gender`, and compare `data$individual_id` with `row_data$individual_id`. With that being said, there are likely alternative/better ways to recode this, but thought this would help for a start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you intended to have "2" for individuals who have "one" female sibling (and not 2 or more female siblings).

In addition to above comment regarding use of "data" as both the data.frame name as well as the argument of your function, you could try the following approach.

Using tidyverse, you can group by `family_id` and then use `map_int` from purrr to go through each row within a family. The `row_number()` indicates the row to be removed from the family, such that you can evaluate the result of the family siblings to see who is male and female. So, `gender[-.x]` will effectively contain all rows for a given family *except* the current row based on `row_number()`.

For reproducibility, I might be explicit in defining each case with `case_when`. Let me know if this provides the expected output.

```
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  group_by(family_id) |>
  mutate(siblings_composition = map_int(
    row_number(),
    ~ case_when(
      all(c("M", "F") %in% gender[-.x]) ~ 3,
      "F" %in% gender[-.x] ~ 2,
      "M" %in% gender[-.x] ~ 1,
      .default = 0
  )))
```

**Output**

```
  individual_id family_id gender siblings_composition
          <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                 <int>
1             1         1 M                         2
2             2         1 F                         1
3             3         2 M                         2
4             4         2 F                         1
5             5         3 M                         0
6             6         4 M                         2
7             7         4 F                         1
8             8         5 M                         2
9             9         5 F                         1
```

**Edit (11/7/23):**

Additional data provided in original post. The code has been revised to match the column names.

```
data |>
  group_by(BIRIMNO) |>
  mutate(siblings_composition = map_int(
    row_number(),
    ~ case_when(
      all(c("M", "F") %in% CINSIYET[-.x]) ~ 3,
      "F" %in% CINSIYET[-.x] ~ 2,
      "M" %in% CINSIYET[-.x] ~ 1,
      .default = 0
  )))
```

**Output**

```
   BIRIMNO CINSIYET       id siblings_composition
     <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>                <int>
 1  144003 F        14400307                    1
 2  144003 M        14400306                    2
 3  144009 F        14400903                    0
 4  144014 M        14401409                    0
 5  144015 M        14401501                    0
 6  144016 M        14401603                    0
 7  144020 F        14402003                    2
 8  144020 F        14402004                    2
 9  144021 F        14402103                    0
10  144025 F        14402503                    3
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I run the code but it produced the following error message: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `siblings_composition = map_int(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: family_id = 1.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Case 4 (`all(c("M", "F") %in% gender[-.x]) ~ 3`) must be a two-sided formula, not a double vector.

Comment: in the siblings_composition column, I need 0 if no siblings, 1 if at least 1 male sibling, 2 for at least 1 female sibling, and 3 for both male and female siblings

Comment: @SelinErdogan It might help if you could share a sample of your data for reproducibility. Can you use `dput(head(data, 100))` and copy/paste the result by editing your original post above? Then, I can try to reproduce. Also, did you try to run the code with your example data, and did it work? Finally, is the result not what you were looking for? If not, could you edit your post, and include what the `siblings_composition` should include for the 9 rows in your example?

Comment: @SelinErdogan One other note - did you try to correct your function based on my comment to your post above? I corrected it at my end, and I get the same result for `siblings_composition` with the example data above, which led me to believe the the tidyverse version provided the expected outcome result.

Comment: Hello again- I applied the code but it didn't produce the expected outcome which I provided in the post above. For example, for the first family (144003) there are 2 siblings, one is female (14400307) one is male (14400306). I want siblings_composition for them to be 1 and 2, respectively, but it is 3. For the family 144009 there is only 1 child so siblings_composition should be 0 but it is 3. The code works for the example dataset but does not work in the original dataset as expected.

Comment: @SelinErdogan Hi - thanks for sharing your sample of data - it is very helpful. I revised the code to match the column names, and I do get the desired output (for example, I get 1 and 2 for `BIRIMNO` 144003). I will edit my answer to show the new code with substituted names. I'm not sure what the discrepancy is. I see the data already has `siblings_composition` but it should be rewritten when the code is run. Perhaps reset your R session (clear objects), copy/paste the `data` data.frame you shared, and copy/paste the revised code, and see if that works?

Comment: @SelinErdogan Also, I would check what version you have of `tidyverse`. Perhaps update this as well, as that could make a difference. Further, if this still doesn't work, you can copy/paste `sessionInfo()` into your post, to show what versions of packages are loaded at the time of running the code. Good luck!

Comment: it worked, many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "2" is at least 1 female

```
library(dplyr)
count_data <- data |> 
  summarize(count = n(),.by = c(family_id,gender)) |> 
  mutate(type = case_when(gender == "M" & count >=1 ~ 1,
                          gender == "F" & count >=1 ~ 2)) |> 
  summarise(class = sum(type), .by = family_id)

left_join(data, count_data, by = "family_id")

#  individual_id family_id gender class
# 1             1         1      M     3
# 2             2         1      F     3
# 3             3         2      M     3
# 4             4         2      F     3
# 5             5         3      M     1
# 6             6         4      M     3
# 7             7         4      F     3
# 8             8         5      M     3
# 9             9         5      F     3
```